# how to force a user to select one optionbutton vba

Tags: vba, radio-button

I have a vba userform in word with two option buttons and a Ok and Cancel button.

If the user don't select any of the option buttons, I want to show a msgbox saying that he have to select one option.

Probably I have to use a for loop but I'm not seeing how.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Henrique

Answer (score 0):

```
If ((Me.OptionButton1.Value = 0) * (Me.OptionButton2.Value = 0)) Then
    MsgBox "not selected"
End If
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But if the user choose to not select any option button and click OK, the code is going to my next userform and I want to show again this userform until the user choose one of two option buttons.